# sql server 2012 offset return same record

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a strange problem with SQL Server 2012.

I use a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```

Every time I use this query from 0 to 25, 25 to 50, 50 to 75, 75 to 100, it returns the same 25 records.

When I use it with 100 to 125, it returns the original 25 to 50 etc...

My table contains only 197 records and this happens only with one table of my database. All other tables work correctly.

This also happens when I use the query via code (ASP.NET C#) and from SQL Management Studio directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your logic a little bit, to include which page is active:

```
DECLARE @pagesize AS BIGINT = 25, @pagenum AS BIGINT = 3; 

SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY field 
OFFSET @pagesize * @pagenum ROWS FETCH NEXT @pagesize ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: I've already done this in my c# code so my query is the result of a similar logic

Comment: If this logic is done on database side, it should be faster :)

Comment: Moving the logic in the database side will resolve my original problem, but now the query does not return all the records.
I've 197 records, 25 records per page, in the page n8 i've only 5 records in stead of 22 (25*7 = 175 so in the page 8 i need 22 records)

Comment: Weird, maybe your column in `ORDER BY` is not deterministic, and make problem. Can `field` column can contain duplicates? If so, add primary key column in `ORDER BY` clause, after `field` column.

Comment: "field" column is datetime

Comment: Any progress with your problem?

Comment: without the "-1" on the pagesize i need to start from page 0, then I try to add the "-1" to the pagenum and the query return the correct records

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue: the query always returned the same rows independently on the Offset value (30):

```
OFFSET 30 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

For me [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783608#comment22442296_15784368) by [veljasije](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600032) is the correct answer:

> Weird, maybe your column in ORDER BY is not deterministic, and make
> problem. Can field column can contain duplicates? If so, add primary
> key column in ORDER BY clause, after field column.

I solved this issue by adding [ID] column into Order By:

```
ORDER BY [Status], [ID] ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

`OFFSET FETCH NEXT` freaks out if the column that you are ordering by does not contain unique data. To “fake” a distinct column you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() over (order by field) 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the column in the orderby must be unique.Thanks